# Cannot run dockerfile successfully with pycharm

Tags: windows, docker, pycharm

When I run dockerfile with code

```
FROM python:3.10-slim as builder

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc

COPY . .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /wheels -r requirements.txt


# final stage
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /app .

RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

It failed with errors below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqlHa.png)

Who could please tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential` at the beginning should solve it.